# Cannot delete property of an object in an array- React,redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have an array, which is from redux-store, contains list of object. I use delete operator to delete some certain property of object in the array in a function, but return an errors "Cannot delete property 'message' of #"
[image]
Below as my codes:

```
const transactionSuccess = (data) => {
    notifySuccess("payment success");
    console.log("products", products);
    for (const item of products) {
      delete item.message;
      delete item.sizes;
    }

    const userLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    const { token } = userLocal;
    const object = {
      products: products,
      isPaid: data.paid,
      description: "paypal;",
    };
    postAPICart(object, token, history);
  };
```

console.log('products', products) returns 3 objects in an array
[image]

Comment: try create a copy of the list object first and then modify it, ` const copyProducts = [...products]; `

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I really appreciate andres and phry for trying to help me with that question.

I finally reach out the key problem in my code, it's all about shadow and deep copy

const products = [{item1},{item2}] // an array contains list of object
const copiedProducts = [...products] or const copiedProducts = products.map(item => item) will return SHADOW COPPY of products. Spread operator and map dont actually create new item1 and item2 object. Therefore, if you try to delete or add new property in item1 or item2 of copiedProducts, item1 and 2 in original products also be override, then complier then return an error

I came up with this solution:
const productsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products)); // create a deep copy, all objects are totally separated from original one
Below is a link help me above solution:
[https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/3-ways-to-copy-objects-in-javascript/#:~:text=A%20deep%20copying%20means%20that,connected%20to%20the%20original%20variable](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/3-ways-to-copy-objects-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=A%20deep%20copying%20means%20that,connected%20to%20the%20original%20variable).

Happy coding day guys

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change values in your store outside of a reducer. And now you may say "hey, this is not a store value", but it most likely is just a reference to the store - and changing any of your `products` here would in turn also change the store.

You can do something like this:

```
const newProducts = products.map(({ message, sizes, ...rest }) => rest)
```

this will leave the original objects alone and create an array of new objects with everything except `messages` and `size` for you to work with